# How can I restrict a user to login only once in 24 hours? in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to restrict content usage. What I need to achieve is that once a user logs out they can not login for next 24 hours. Or If thats not doable how can I do that a user can only login once in 24 hours? Using WordPress

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this situation by adding a custom field let's say `last_login_timestamp` for the profile (i.e. when user register). Basically whenever user logout you can update this custom field by using `wp_logout` hook. something like

```
function slug_update_user_last_login_hook() {
    if(! is_admin()) { // obviously not for admin
      // logic to update custom form field for user
    }
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'slug_update_user_last_login_hook');
```

And when user login you can check whether or not the last login time is less than or equal to 24 hour or not.

```
function slug_24_hour_login_check() {
        if(! is_admin()) { // obviously not for admin
          //compare the the time of custom form field of logged in user's id
          //if not you can logout user and redirect to another page using wp_redirect
          wp_redirect( $url_of_24_hour_login_notice );
        }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'slug_24_hour_login_check');
```

Let me know how it works out.